# Propositional logic a or b or TRUE

Tags: propositional-calculus

If I have a formula $a \vee b\vee True $

What's the number of states where this is true ?

Does the W even matter? Or is it for cases where

a and b are 0 and the whole function is true, due to the W ?

Comment: It is always True, i.e.a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). Check it with the [truth table for $\lor$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction_(OR)).

Comment: So $(x \vee y \vee z \vee w) \wedge (x \vee y \vee z \vee \neg w)$ Would be a contradiction?

Comment: No; it is enough that one of $x,y,z$ is True. You have to review the basic def: tautology, contradiction,...

Comment: Ah yes. But the part $(w \wedge \neg w)$ becomes irrelevant in general, due to the fact that this or part can not become true?

Comment: 1: What's W? 2: Make a truth table